# using Pouchdb change feed how to start from first change

Tags: pouchdb, cloudant

I am listening on a database which only have writes.
For that I am using following code :

```js
db.changes({
 since: 'now',
 live: true,
 include_docs: true
}).on('change', function (change) {
   // change.id contains the doc id, change.doc contains the doc
}).on('error', function (err) {
// handle errors
});
```

since: 'now' start listening to changes from now, I want to start listening from a first doc and when I catch up I want to listen to live changes.

Is there any way I can start from a first change to database and then get live changes?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "a first doc" - do you mean the first change in the database? If you mean "from the first change", then you can pass in '1' to since and then it will start from the beginning. Each change will then call the 'on change' handler, whether it is an old change or a future change.

Comment: @MikeMcKay Thanks for a comment, when I see changes in couch db, I see seq no as a number followed by a random string. So I was confused that if I try with 1 only, will it still goes through a start of the change in db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the "since" option and it will always start at the first change sequence of the database. It will then call the "change" handler for each change that has ever occurred in the database and will also call the "change" handler for all future changes. I have *not* tested this on CouchDB 2.0, which does use a different format for sequence numbers ( "strings, not numbers, as it encodes the numeric sequences of each shard of the database") but I expect leaving out the since option will work the same way.